# finding missing date from a column with date with data.table in R

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data.table dt, which looks like:

```
> dt[1:20, c("p_date", "p_time")]
        p_date           p_time
 1:      20170422          0916
 2:      20170421          1011         
 3:      20170112          1528
 4:      20170318          1111
 5:      20170322          0957
 6:      20170321          1115
 7:      20170304          1532
 8:      20170322          1417
 9:      20170401          1242
10:      20170321          1812
11:      20170401          1821
12:      20170401          1509
13:      20170320          1655
14:      20170401          1518
15:      20170320          1444
16:      20170401          1712
17:      20170317          1021
18:      20170322          1816
19:      20170305          1056
20:      20170319          1428
```

I want to find out which date are missing from the values of column p_date of table dt.

Here the date is in the format of yyyymmdd, I want to find out the missing date between the minimum date and the maximum date value present in the list.

The output must be a data.table with one column as the missing date values

How can I do this with data.table in r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a vector of dates between your minimum and your maximum date like this:

```
dateRangeVec <- range(as.Date(as.character(dt$p_date), format = "%Y%m%d")) 
allDatesVec <- format(seq(from = dateRangeVec[1], 
        to = dateRangeVec[2], 'days'), "%Y%m%d")
```

You can then filter all the dates that are not in your data table using `setdiff`:

```
outDt <- data.table(p_date = setdiff(allDatesVec, dt$p_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a join `on` 'p_date' (after converting the column to `Date` class) by creating another dataset with the full range of 'p_date'

```
dt[, p_date := lubridate::ymd(p_date)]
dt1 <- data.table(p_date = seq(min(dt$p_date), max(dt$p_date), by = '1 day'))

dt[dt1, on = 'p_date'][is.na(p_time), p_date]
```

---

Or another option is to use `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(dt1, dt, on = 'p_date')
```

Comment: Are you aware of what `min(dt$p_date):max(dt$p_date)` actually produces? The `p_date` column is not a `Date`. Your final result will contain dates like `20170399`.

Comment: @nicola Okay, i converted to `Date` class

Comment: Data.table also has anti-joins, fyi, like `X[!Y]`